# Proving that $a^m \equiv 1 \bmod{n}$ if and only if $k\mid m$ for $k=\operatorname{ord}_n(a)$

Tags: number-theory

> Let $a$ and $n$ be natural numbers with $(a,n)=1$, let $k=\operatorname{ord}_n(a)$ and let $m$ be a natural number. Then $a^m \equiv 1 \bmod{n}$ if and only if $k\mid m$.

Where do I start to prove this theorem?

Answer (score 1):

**A Start:** We have $m=kq+r$, for some integers $q$ and $r$, with $0\le r\lt k$. Note that
$$a^m=a^{kq+r}=a^{kq}a^r.$$

Comment: since $k=ord_k(a)$ it is the smallest natural number: $am≡1(modn)$, which is 1 so r must be zero?

Comment: It is an if and only if question. For the easy direction, if $m=kq$, then $a^m=(a^k)^q\equiv 1^q=1$. For the harder direction, if $a^m\equiv 1$, then since $a^{kq}\equiv 1$, we get from my answer that $a^r\equiv 1$. since $k\lt r$, this contradicts the fact that $k$ is the order of $a$, unless $r=0$.

Comment: how do you know $(a^k)^q ≡1^q =1$? Im sorry I am very lost with this problem.

Comment: We are told that $k$ is the order of $a$ (modulo $n$). That means, by definition, that $k$ is the smallest positive integer such that $a^k\equiv 1\pmod{n}$. That's why we can write $a^k\equiv 1\pmod{n}$, and therefore $(a^k)^q\equiv 1^q\equiv 1\pmod{n}$.

Comment: does this then mean k|m? that's where I'm having trouble putting it all together

Comment: **If** $a^m\equiv 1\pmod{n}$, it does imply that $k$ divides $m$. For from $a^m\equiv 1\pmod{n}$, we conclude that $1\equiv a^m=(a^k)^qa^r\pmod{n}$. But $(a^k)^q\equiv 1\pmod{n}$, and therefore $a^r\equiv 1\pmod{n}$. If $r\ne 0$, that means there is a positive integer $w\lt k$, namely $r$, such that $a^w\equiv 1\pmod{n}$. That contradicts the fact that $k$ is the order of $a$. the only way out is to have $r=0$, meaning that the remainder when you divide $m$ by $k$ is $0$, which means $k$ divides $m$.